# How to remove unicode, convert strings to integers, when reading in CSV and then dump to JSON?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have the following data in a csv file:

```
East Valley School (Yakima) District, 34218434
Colville School District, 20144144
Toledo School District, 8123819
```

I'm reading in the csv file and then dumping it to a json file.

```
csv_file = open('Data.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
headers = dict(reader)

with open('file.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(headers, outfile, ensure_ascii=True)
```

My data comes out looking like this:

```
{u'East Valley School (Yakima) District': u'34218434', u'Colville School District': u'20144144', u'Toledo School District': u'8123819'}
```

I want to remove the unicode from the json keys and I want the items to be integers. As I understand it, this is something that I need to do when I'm reading in the csv file but at I'm at a loss for what I need to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this really the content that appears in `file.json` not on the console? I fail to reproduce your issue in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: This is what shows up in the console.

Comment: Ok, in that case you are seeing the output of the Python dictionary rather than the JSON and should simply ignore the `u` prefixes on strings. The JSON output should not have them.

Comment: That's odd. When I load the JSON file back into my console and print it that's the output I get.

Comment: Do you use `json.load()`? In that case, that output is indeed a Python `dict`, rather than the JSON string written to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `u` string prefixes, you appear to be looking at the printed Python dictionary rather than the JSON output. So that should not be an issue.

To convert the numbers to integers, you'll just need to add

```
for k, v in headers.items():
    headers[k] = int(v)
```